# Adding in a TextView programatically shows no text

Tags: android

I'm adding in a TextView programatically to a linear layout.  I can see the background image but for some reason the text is never displayed.  Any ideas?  Here's the code:

```
TextView pointsTV = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
pointsTV.setText("Test Should Show");
pointsTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
pointsTV.setTextColor(android.R.color.white);
pointsTV.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
pointsTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gamesummary_bottom);
pointsTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
ll.addView(pointsTV);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the colour to a numeric value, which causes it to disappear. Use

```
pointsTV.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
```

In order to use setTextColor(), you have to give it a statelist or hex instead of a colour value. 
[The salient bit of the developer guide is here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29)

Comment: That was it!  pointsTV.setTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));   Thankyou!